# select query with foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: db - schema]

I have a three table schema (see image above) Articles, Tags and ArticleTags. The ArticleTags table maps article_id to a tag_id. Im trying to retrieve all rows from Articles and join the tags associated with each row.

Comment: Do u want to retrieve the Articles without a Tag too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.article_id, group_concat(t.tag_name) as tag_names
from articles a
left join ArticleTags at on at.article_id = a.article_id
left join tags t on at.tag_id = t.tag_id
group by a.article_id
```

Comment: I forgot to add the query i'd been trying. similar to what you have. This query results in duplication of rows. I was trying a group_concat(a.article_id). Essentially I'm looking for an array of tags for each article_id. 

``select a.*, t.tag_name, group_concat(a.article_id)
from articles a
left join ArticleTags at on at.article_id = a.article_id
left join tags t on at.tag_id = t.tag_id``

Comment: worked like a charm! I was about to make two separate queries and manipulate the outputs in JS.